# $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to 0} |zf(z)| = 0$ implies $z = 0$ is a removable singularity.

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that $f$ is analytic around $z = 0$ and that $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to 0} |zf(z)| = 0$, we can conclude that $f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z = 0$.

I think that we should deduce that $f(z)$ is bounded around $z = 0$ and use Riemann to conclude that it has a removable singularity. However, I have no idea how to show that this must be bounded. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(z) = zf(z)$. By assumption $g$ is bounded near $z=0$, so $g$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$. Hence
$$f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z},$$
on a punctured neighbourhood of $z=0$. Since $g(0) = 0$, it follows that $g(z) = zh(z)$ for some analytic function $h$, i.e.
$$f = h$$
on a punctured neighbourhood of $z=0$, which shows that $f$ is bounded near $0$.

Comment: Why does f=h imply that f is bounded near 0?

Comment: $h$ is analytic (on a full neighbourhood of $0$)